# Why does the onClick function not fire directly on this component?

Tags: reactjs

If I put an onClick event directly on my React component, the function doesn't fire. Here's an example with a function called setMenuIsOpen that does not fire when the Burger component is clicked.

```
<Burger onClick={() => setMenuIsOpen(!menuIsOpen)} />
```

However, if I wrap the component in a div and move the onClick event, the setMenuIsOpen event fires as expected.

```
<div onClick={() => setMenuIsOpen(!menuIsOpen)}>
<Burger />
</div>
```

Can someone please explain the reason for this behavior and the recommended pattern for handling click events on components? I'm guessing the correct approach is to implement the function inside of the Burger component and pass the event as a prop. But it seems a little more intuitive that the event and state change should be handled one level higher.

**Edit - I should note that my Burger component also contains an onclick event within it that toggles the appearance between a "burger" state and an "X" state. That works fine. It's when I import the burger component on a page and attempt to trigger a second menu component that I run into the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone please explain the reason for this behavior

It sounds like `Burger` does not look for and use its `onClick` prop. Eg:

```js
const Burger = () => {
    return <div>Burger</div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Burger onClick={() => console.log('click')} />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

In contrast, a `<div>` will always accept and recognize an `onClick` prop.

> the recommended pattern for handling click events on components

Best way would be to define the child component to take an `onClick` prop, and use it:

```js
const Burger = ({ onClick = () => void 0 }) => {
    return <div onClick={onClick}>Burger</div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Burger onClick={() => console.log('click')} />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

If you can't change the child component, surrounding the whole child in another, and putting the click listener on the parent, may be your only other option.